# Complex SQL query, checking column values in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a pretty huge SQL query to check for notifications, and I have several different types of notifications in the table, IE: posts, likes, comments, photoComments, photoLikes, videoLikes, etc. (Always adding more to it) And I have come into a problem, I'm not really sure how to best do this anymore. Thus far the way I have done it is working perfectly, and really quite easy to add to, however this one notification Type I have to check more than just one other table, I have to check two others and I haven't been able to get it to work.

So here it is: (This is only one part of my huge query, the only relevant part really)

```
n.uniqueID = ANY (
              SELECT photos.id
              FROM photos INNER JOIN posts ON (photos.id=posts.post)
              WHERE photos.state=0
              AND posts.state=0 
              AND posts.id = ANY (
                                   SELECT likes.postID FROM likes
                                   INNER JOIN posts ON (posts.id=likes.postID)
                                   WHERE likes.state=0 AND posts.state=0
                                  )
                )
```

So basically all I really need to do is check the `state` columns in each table because that says whether or not it is deleted or not (if it's not 0 then it's deleted and shouldn't be returned) 
So it would be like:

`IF photos.state=0 AND posts.state=0 AND likes.state=0` return it.

- `n.uniqueID`, `posts.post`, and `photo.id` will all be the same
  value.
- `posts.id` and `likes.postID` will also be the same value.

My issue is that it doesn't seem to be checking the `likes.state`, I don't think.

Comment: Just a thought here- those subqueries can get very expensive. Depending on your situation you might consider doing more, smaller queries if possible. That's not always a good suggestion because it depends on your specific situation, but doing 2 or 3 queries instead of one deeply nested one can often times be much *more* efficient.  YMMV

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I know what you're saying but I have spent a long time recoding this query for this particular system, and this seems to be the best/simplest way I and many stackoverflow users have been able to come up. This large query above is only one of about seven (and growing) in this one particular query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to join the three tables together in a single query:

```
n.uniqueID = ANY (
              SELECT photos.id
              FROM photos INNER JOIN
                   posts
                   ON photos.id=posts.post inner join
                   likes
                   on posts.id = likes.postId
              WHERE photos.state=0 and
                    posts.state=0 and
                    likes.state = 0
                  )
```

Your logic is not to return when there is a like or post with the state of 0.  It seems to be that *all* the likes and posts have a state of zero.  For this, do an aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
n.uniqueID = ANY (
              SELECT photos.id
              FROM photos INNER JOIN
                   posts
                   ON photos.id=posts.post inner join
                   likes
                   on posts.id = likes.postId
              where photos.state = 0
              group by photos.id
              having MAX(posts.state) = 0 and MAX(likes.state) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks this is definitely less code, I am using this and the problem still persists. The issue is still with the likes, because it only has problems when there is a row in the likes table with the same postID, even though the state is set to 1. I tried changing a row in your query but it doesn't do anything. `on posts.id = likes.postID AND likes.state=0`

Comment: And when I say it doesn't do anything, I mean it still is returning the first row with a specific postID even though it has a state of 1

Comment: `Your logic is not to return when there is a like or post with the state of 0` No, I only want to return said rows with a state of 0.