# MySQL: Determine if Date Exists in Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I am building a monthly statistics form system. The front page of the system shows either a '+' if no statistics have been set for a certain month and a [pencil glyphicon] if there have been statistics set.

The front page looks similar to this (pencil glyph replaced with pipe)

```
Year 2014
Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
 +    +    +    |    +    |    |    |    |    |    |    |

Year 2013
Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
 +    +    +    +    +    |    |    |    +    |    +    |
```

...and so on.

Simple enough.

But the problem is that I am not just checking one table to see if its "month_id" field equals the month; I am checking 7 different tables. All 7 tables have the common field "month_id".

If ANY of the 7 tables contain a month_id that matches the current month, the pencil glyph should be shown. If not, a '+'.

I don't need any help generating the HTML or PHP for this, just advice on if there is an effective way to query the database.

Comment: this link might b helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222605/complex-sql-query-checking-column-values-in-multiple-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE month_id = MONTH(CURDATE()))
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE month_id = MONTH(CURDATE()))
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE month_id = MONTH(CURDATE()))
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table4 WHERE month_id = MONTH(CURDATE()))
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table5 WHERE month_id = MONTH(CURDATE()))
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table6 WHERE month_id = MONTH(CURDATE()))
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table7 WHERE month_id = MONTH(CURDATE()));
```

If the result is greater than 0, you have at least one matching row among the seven tables.